# Nested dispatch_async (dispatch_async inside another dispatch_async)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nested, dispatch-async

How I call properly `dispatch_async` calls inside `dispatch_async`

```
dispatch_group_t downloadQueue = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(downloadQueue,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {

NSLog(@"Main");
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
NSLog(@"End");

    [self myMethod];

});
dispatch_group_notify(downloadQueue,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0), ^ {

    NSLog(@"FINAL");

});
```

and here is myMethod :

```
-(void)myMethod
{
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        // block1
        NSLog(@"Block1");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
        NSLog(@"Block1 End");
    });
    dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        // block2
        NSLog(@"Block2");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:8.0];
        NSLog(@"Block2 End");
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        // block3
        NSLog(@"Block3");
    });
}
```

**and my output is :**

Main

End

Block1

Block2

FINAL

Block1 End 

Block2 End

Block3

**but i need**

Main

End

Block1

Block2

Block1 End 

Block2 End

Block3

FINAL

Comment: Your problem is that `myMethod` is asynchronous so it will dispatch its blocks and then return, exiting the outer dispatch group. Use dispatch_group_enter and dispatch_group_leave rather than dispatch_group_async

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be notified with group of yours `myMethod`. Yours code will be:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {

    NSLog(@"Main");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
    NSLog(@"End");

    dispatch_group_notify([self myMethod],dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0), ^ {

        NSLog(@"FINAL");

    });
});

-(dispatch_group_t)myMethod{

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        // block1
        NSLog(@"Block1");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
        NSLog(@"Block1 End");
    });


    dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        // block2
        NSLog(@"Block2");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:8.0];
        NSLog(@"Block2 End");
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        // block3
        NSLog(@"Block3");
    });
    return group;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dispatch_group_wait** in `myMethod` istead of dispatch_group_notify. This way your method will return only when both dispatch_group_async finish executing.